# In git what does "Commits by domain" mean?

Tags: git

We ran gitstats and under the commits by domain we have some strange domains in their including another company(foo.com) that's down the street. Does anyone know where that information comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the domain of the user that committed it.  I found out I could search my repo for who it was using

```
git log --author=Linus
```

That showed the user that was using the in question domain.

Comment: Right. Specifically, it's coming from the author field's email address.